# find index of a string in a structure field

Tags: string, matlab, indexing, structure

I have a structure STRUCT (1x70 struct) with 12 fields. The first field LAB contains strings in each cell (e.g., 'ab1', 'fj3', 'INPUT', 'OUTPUT', etc.). I need to find the index of the string 'INPUT'.

```
STRUCT = struct('LAB',{'ab1', 'fj3', 'INPUT', 'OUTPUT'},'fieldname2',{10,32,53,14})
```

I have tried with the following lines of code, but each of those did not work.

```
idx = strfind(STRUCT.LAB, 'INPUT'); %Error using strfind Unrecognized parameter name 'INPUT'.

idx = ([STRUCT.LAB]=='INPUT') %Matrix dimensions must agree.

idx = find(strcmp([STRUCT.LAB], 'INPUT')) %ans: [] rather than 3.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. Wrap `STRUCT.LAB` in a cell:

```
idx = find(strcmp({STRUCT.LAB},'INPUT'))
```